# sonar-runner.bat JAVA_HOME doesn't point to a valid Java home

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I would like to analyse a simple java project for testing sonarQube installation.
However when i run sonar-runner. bat i have this error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Java installation is not correct. You should test the value of `JAVA_HOME` variable by executing  `Get-Item Env:JAVA_HOME` in PowerShell and verify that it points to a valid Java installation.

Alternatively, you can download [sonar-scanner for Windows](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0.1227-windows.zip) which already includes Java runtime.